# Failed to fetch ........... Hash Sum mismatch

Tags: docker, windows-10, apt-get

#### Environment

- OS: Windows 10
- Docker Version: 2.1.0.3 Stable Desktop Community
- Docker Compose Version: 1.24.1

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:11

COPY ./99fixbadproxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fixbadproxy

RUN apt-get -y update \
  && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    python3-dev \
    python-gdal \
    libxml2 \
    libgeos-dev \
    libproj12 \
    postgresql-server-dev-11 \
    postgresql-11-postgis-2.5 \
    postgresql-11-postgis-scripts \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ADD ./init /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

99fixbadproxy

```
Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;
Acquire::http::No-Cache true;
Acquire::BrokenProxy    true;
```

#### Docker commands that I executed

`docker-compose build db`

#### Actual result

```
Building db
Step 1/4 : FROM postgres:11
 ---> e2d75d1c1264
Step 2/4 : COPY ./99fixbadproxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fixbadproxy
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5448c38eae1c
Step 3/4 : RUN apt-get -y update   && apt-get install -y     build-essential     python3-dev     python-gdal     libxml2     libgeos-dev     libproj12     postgresql-server-dev-11     postgresql-11-postgis-2.5     postgresql-11-postgis-scripts   && apt-get clean   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Running in d930ce46b46e
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg InRelease [51.4 kB]
Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
Get:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt stretch-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [184 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [27.4 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2,365 B]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7,086 kB]
Get:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [497 kB]
Err:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:497208 [weak]
   - SHA256:2c51a7b9197719053220fc1d4c38453a48582d0190953481c0cd9620b8844a00
   - SHA1:6599fb50a02b4f3abe280b0bbfd42ba6227ae7d4 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:23a00a02efd96accdf62f7e6d27ee44b [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:e8bb756eb3dae9f84b1ff2623bc3ff058e02775f60082cf1583ef789214a4a53
   - SHA1:b8fa8ff140603cb7b64f8f214957f35d1f85b987 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:fbb52af7168bde493aa4d9e6b65c6e34 [weak]
   - Filesize:497208 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 25 Sep 2019 06:37:02 +0000
  Release file created at: Thu, 26 Sep 2019 04:11:51 +0000
Fetched 8,151 kB in 7s (1,106 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/2c51a7b9197719053220fc1d4c38453a48582d0190953481c0cd9620b8844a00  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:497208 [weak]
    - SHA256:2c51a7b9197719053220fc1d4c38453a48582d0190953481c0cd9620b8844a00
    - SHA1:6599fb50a02b4f3abe280b0bbfd42ba6227ae7d4 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:23a00a02efd96accdf62f7e6d27ee44b [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:e8bb756eb3dae9f84b1ff2623bc3ff058e02775f60082cf1583ef789214a4a53
    - SHA1:b8fa8ff140603cb7b64f8f214957f35d1f85b987 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:fbb52af7168bde493aa4d9e6b65c6e34 [weak]
    - Filesize:497208 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Wed, 25 Sep 2019 06:37:02 +0000
   Release file created at: Thu, 26 Sep 2019 04:11:51 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y update   && apt-get install -y     build-essential     python3-dev     python-gdal     libxml2     libgeos-dev     libproj12     postgresql-server-dev-11     postgresql-11-postgis-2.5     postgresql-11-postgis-scripts   
&& apt-get clean   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

#### Expected outcome

```
Successfully built
```

This image perfectly work fine in any distro of Linux, I have tested in Ubuntu, Debian, Arch Linux. And I didn't even included Step 2.

I added step 2 according to following link but unfortunately it didn't work for me.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/543

#### Output of `docker version`

Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.2
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.8
 Git commit:        6a30dfc
 Built:             Thu Aug 29 05:26:49 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.2
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.8
  Git commit:       6a30dfc
  Built:            Thu Aug 29 05:32:21 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.6
  GitCommit:        894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8
  GitCommit:        425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683

#### Other relevant information

- I tried both automatic and fixed DNS Server settings.
- I tried exposing daemon on tcp without TLS checked and unchecked, thinking could be the issue of networking.
- My proxies is disabled.
- I tried with other debian based image and added apt-get update line. However, it doesn't seem s to work anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your RUN to this:

```
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial && apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz \
  && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    python3-dev \
    python-gdal \
    libxml2 \
    libgeos-dev \
    libproj12 \
    postgresql-server-dev-11 \
    postgresql-11-postgis-2.5 \
    postgresql-11-postgis-scripts
```

That happened to me a lot, until I found this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/779924). It solved that problem with my builds.

Answer (score 0):

For the above problem, what I did was just update my freshly installed windows and restarted computer. Then when I run the same Dockerfile again.

Wolla! It worked. Don't know how things went well on a sudden. I haven't change anything in the middle. So, anyone can explain why this happen.